# I can't use a route::post in Laravel (Error 419 (unknown status))

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I have a code of Ajax, it works with the type="get" but I want to change the type to "post"

```
$.ajax({
    url:   '/crear',
    type:  'post',
    cache: 'false',
    contentType: 'false',
    processData: 'false',
    data:  {'nombre':Vnombre,'codigo':Vcodigo,'descripcion':Vdescripcion,'arrayCategorias':arrayCategoriasAux,'arrayColores':arrayColoresAux,'arrayTallas':arrayTallasAux}
}).done(function(data){

    window.location.replace("/almacen/producto");
});
```

I changed my route in web.php

```
Route::post('/crear', 'ProductoController@store');
```

But It didn't work, I have the error 419 (unknown status) in my Browser

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

```html
<script src="{{asset('js/jquery-3.2.1.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

My Controller:

```html
    public function store(ProductoFormRequest $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()) {

            if (!(empty($request->nombre)) && !(empty($request->codigo)) && !(empty($request->descripcion))) {

                # code...
                $producto              = new Producto;
                $producto->codigo      = $request->codigo;
                $producto->nombre      = $request->nombre;
                $producto->descripcion = $request->descripcion;
                $producto->stock       = '0';
                 $producto->estado = '1';
                $producto->save();
            }
        }
    }
```

My Request

```html
<?php

namespace sistema\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ProductoFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'codigo'      => 'required|max:45',
            'nombre'      => 'required|max:45',
            'descripcion' => 'max:45',
            'stock'       => 'max:11',
        ];
    }
}
```

Only i want to send Files [] and others arrays [] to my controller, if anyone has a better idea please help me

My Form

```html
<form onsubmit="FuncionGuardar();"  method="Post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" id="add_user_form">
{{csrf_field()}}
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <label for="codigo"> Nombre</label>

  <input class="form-control" required value="{{old('nombre')}}" type="text" id="inNombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <label for="codigo"> Codigo</label>
  <input class="form-control" required value="{{old('codigo')}}" type="text" id="inCodigo" name="codigo" placeholder="Codigo">
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <label for="codigo"> Descripcion</label>
  <input class="form-control" required value="{{old('descripcion')}}" type="text" id="inDescripcion" name="descripcion" placeholder="Descripcion">
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label>Categorias</label>
    <div class="input-group">
    <select id="CategoriasSelect" name="idt_categoria" class="form-control" >
     @foreach($categorias as $cat)
               <option value="{{$cat->idt_categoria}}">{{$cat->nombre}}</option>
     @endforeach
    </select>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
           <a class="btn btn-primary " href="#" role="button" onclick="CrearBotonCategorias()">Añadir</a>
         </span>
   </div>
  <small class="text-muted" >*Clic en la Categoria para eliminarla</small>
  <br>
   <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
    <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
     <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="First group" id="DivCategorias">
        <!-- Botones de categorias agregados -->
       </div>
    </div>

   </div>



 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label>Colores</label>
    <div class="input-group">
    <select id="ColoresSelect" name="idt_color" class="form-control" >
     @foreach($colores as $coloKey)
               <option   value="{{$coloKey->idt_color}}" style="background-color:{{$coloKey->color}};">
                {{$coloKey->nombre}}
               </option>
     @endforeach
    </select>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
           <a class="btn btn-primary " href="#" role="button" onclick="CrearBotonColores()">Añadir</a>
         </span>
   </div>
  <small class="text-muted" >*Clic en el Color para eliminarlo</small>
  <br>
   <div class="alert " role="alert">
    <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
       <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="First group" id="DivColores">
        <!-- Botones de categorias agregados -->
       </div>
    </div>
   </div>


 </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label>Tallas</label>
    <div class="input-group">
    <select id="TallasSelect" name="idt_categoria" class="form-control" >
     @foreach($tallas as $tallaKey)
               <option value="{{$tallaKey->idt_talla}}">{{$tallaKey->nombre}}</option>
     @endforeach
    </select>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
           <a class="btn btn-primary " href="#" role="button" onclick="CrearBotonTallas()">Añadir</a>
         </span>
   </div>
   <small class="text-muted" >*Clic en la Talla para eliminarla</small>
  <br>
   <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
    <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
       <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="First group" id="DivTallas">
        <!-- Botones de tallas agregados -->
       </div>
    </div>
   </div>


 </div>
 </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label>Imagenes</label>
    <div class="input-group">
     <input type="file" id="Imagenes" class="filestyle" name="files[]" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" data-btnClass="btn-primary" multiple>

    <output id="list"></output>
   </div>
  <br>
   <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
    <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
       <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="First group" id="DivImagenes">
        <!-- Botones de categorias agregados -->
       </div>
    </div>
   </div>


 </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
   <a class="btn btn-danger" href="javascript:window.history.back();" role="button">Cancelar</a>
  </div>

 </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: can you post html form and make sure your have added token header to ajax

Comment: please read here https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

Comment: Can we see the error? Also as @iCoders just said, you are first missing `csr_token()` as part of your data you are posting

Answer (score 4):

Sample ajax request

```
$('#submit-signup').on("click", function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            var formDataValues = document.forms.namedItem("signup-form");
            var formValues = new FormData(formDataValues);


            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: siteUrl + '/signup',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
                data: formValues,

                success: function (data) {



                },
                error: function (data) {

                }
            });
        });
```

**Updated**
419 error becasue of you have not added token in your form
add this line inside form

```
  {{csrf_field()}}
```

**Update 2**
to add form token very simple

```
 <form action="{{url('add-user')}}"  method="Post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" id="add_user_form">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            <div class="form-body">
                <h3 class="form-section">Person Info</h3>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">First Name</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control first_name"  placeholder="First Name">

                            </div>
                        </div>

        </form>
```

Comment: when I put "headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') }," i have the error 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

Comment: it means validation erorr i think.you have valdiation that failes

Comment: for testing purpose use   Request instead of ProductoFormRequest in controller method then it will work .it means your validation fails.

Comment: If my Script is after of my Jquery, i could have a problem?

Comment: @DiegoZerkk.please remove   'codigo'      => 'required|max:45',
            'nombre'      => 'required|max:45',
            'descripcion' => 'max:45',
            'stock'       => 'max:11', this from rule and test .if tis working then it measn your validation failes

Comment: @DiegoZerkk. iguess you change ajax url to full url instead of route url  url:   'fulll url/crear',

Comment: could u see my blade pls i don't understand about the token [link](https://github.com/Zerkk/vista/tree/master/.gitignore)

Comment: I changed to url: 'ururl/crear' and my route Route::post('ururl/crear', 'ProductoController@store'); but i have the error 404, could you see my github, I just updated

Comment: url url means your domain url you have to add in ajax .dont change any think in web.php

Comment: im working in localHost for example: http://127.0.0.1:8000/almacen/producto/create

Comment: url:' http://127.0.0.1:8000/almacen/crear' .and dont change any think route

Comment: i think the error is the token but i don't know how  use that

Comment: can you post your  html form

Comment: @DiegoZerkk.i have added sample form with token

Comment: Ok, i edited but I have other error  419 (unknown status) and 405 (Method Not Allowed), where can i write the $.ajaxSetup?