# Unable to pass attached files to controller: 422 Unprocessable Entity

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, dropzone

I'm using Dropzone js to handle multiple file uploads. However, the files aren't passed to the controller. After resolving 419 post error by adding the header code for the CSRF token, 422 unprocessable entity error appeared.

Based on the response at network log, it seems to affect the validation in my other fields which were working fine earlier.

```
{"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"item-name.0":["The item-
name.0 field is required."],"item-quantity.0":["Please Enter Item 
Quantity."],"availableStartDate":["The available start date field is 
required."],"availableEndDate":["The available end date field is 
required."],"preferredTime":["The preferred time field is required."]}}
```

Here are the Javascript codes at the top of the Blade file.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        new Dropzone('#fileInput', {
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            uploadMultiple: true,
            parallelUploads: 1000,
            maxFiles: 100,
            acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
            url: '/make-a-donation',
            addRemoveLinks:true,
            headers: {
                'X-CSRFToken': $('meta[name="token"]').attr('content')
            },

            init: function () {

                var myDropzone = this;
                var wrapperThis = this;
                $("#submit-all").click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    myDropzone.processQueue();
                });

                //Removed sending and success functions respectively

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here are the HTML codes:

```
<form class="form-horizontal myForm" method="POST" files="true" action="{{ 
route('postdonation') }}"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{ csrf_field() }}

 <div class="col-md-12">

             <div id="fileInput" class="dropzone">
             <div class="fallback">
             <!--replaced files[] to file-->
             <input name="file" type="file" multiple="multiple" id="fileUpload"/>
             </div>
             </div>
</div>

....

<div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
           <button type="submit" id="submit-all" class="btn btn-primary">
               insert
            </button>
      </div>
 </div>
 ...
 </form>
```

At the controller,

```
   public function store(CreateDonationDetailsRequest $r) {

   //Inserting other data in the form
   .....

  //Previously $r->file('files') as $file to
    foreach ($r->file('file') as $file) {
        $donationImages = new DonationImages();

        // Set the destination path
        $destination = '/donationImagesUpload/';
        // Get the orginal filname or create the filename of your choice
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();

        // Copy the file to the destination folder
        $file->move(public_path($destination), $filename);

        //Insert file name to database
        $donationImages->donation_items_id = $donationItems->id;
        $donationImages->photoName = $filename;

        //Save images to database
        $donationItems->donationImages()->save($donationImages);

    }

    ..
}
```

Comment: form `enctype`?

Comment: @skido already added  enctype="multipart/form-data" at the form tag

Comment: @Enovyne did my updates help?

Comment: @Don't Panic Sort of. Now it leads to another error: 422 unprocessable entity.

Comment: Right now you are only posting the file.  If you have other fields in this form, and they are required by validation, you need to include those values in the data you are posting.  You can do that with the `sending` callback I included in my last update.

Comment: I've got your point. Sorry if this is a noob question but how do I append an old value? Tried                          
 formData.append(input.preferredTime, input.preferredTime);

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about an old value?  BTW you really should not keep editing the question to ask new ones - it defeats the purpose of SO.  Half my answers no longer answer the new question, and ppl who have the same problem(s) you originally had will not find your (original) question and my answers bcs your (original) question doesn't exist any more.

Comment: Alright, I'll take note next time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156212/discussion-between-dont-panic-and-enovyne).

Comment: @Enovyne Did my answers help?

Comment: Thanks @Don't Panic. Appending data at the sending() callback worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem 1**

Your submit handler selector is `#submit-all`:

```
$("#submit-all").click(function (e) {
```

But your button does not have that ID (and neither does anything else):

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
```

So your submit handler is never fired, which means `processQueue()` is never called, so no files are actually POSTed.

**Problem 2**

The next problem that you are trying to append the files to `formData`, but they are already there - that's what `processQueue()` does.  You can remove your `sending` event handler completely.

**Problem 3**

Next, [from the Dropzone docs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#usage):

> The uploaded files can be handled just as if there would have been a html input like this:  `<input type="file" name="file" />`

So in your controller, you should be looking for an input named `file`, not `files`:

```
foreach ($r->file('file') as $file) {
```

**Problem 4**

Next, in your `success` callback, you are trying to access the Javascript event as `e`, and the uploaded `file` but neither of those is defined there, so will throw errors.   [According to the docs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-success), the POST response is available as the 2nd parameter, but I am not sure what the 1st is (console log shows it is some kind of Dropzone object).

Note though that the docs also say:

> Do not overwrite those as configuration options, unless you know what you're doing.

I would remove that `success` callback completely.  If you want to remove the file after successful upload, [the docs show exactly how to do that](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#dropzone-methods):

```
myDropzone.on("complete", function(file) {
  myDropzone.removeFile(file);
});
```

Fixing each of these issues, I got your code working correctly in my local environment.

Another thing, I am not sure if it just a typo here on SO, or if you really have this in your code, but you are missing a space in your fallback file input between `multiple` and its `id`, which would probably mess it up in the case when it is needed:

```
multiple="multiple"id="fileUpload"
```

**UPDATE to answer new problem 5**

For your new problem, `419` is typically bcs your CSRF token check is failing.  There are several examples with solutions here on SO: [example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46472812/ajax-laravel-419-post-error), [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46250749/i-cant-use-a-routepost-in-laravel-error-419-unknown-status)

For one of my own projects I use the Dropzone `sending` callback to include other form inputs in the POSTed data:

```
this.on('sending', function(file, xhr, formData) {
    // Append all form inputs to the formData Dropzone will POST
    var data = $('form').serializeArray();
    $.each(data, function(key, el) {
        formData.append(el.name, el.value);
    });
});
```

**UPDATE to answer new problem 6**

For your new problem:

> Now it leads to another error: 422 unprocessable entity

[Laravel returns 422](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#validation-quickstart) for an AJAX request which fails validation.

So it sounds like you have a) more fields in the form than you've shown, and b) validation on them.  Currently, you are only POSTing the file, nothing else, so naturally your validation will fail.

In that case, you'll need to include the other fields in your POST.  You can do that by appending them to `formData`, as shown above in the `sending` callback I included in my previous update.

Comment: I've omitted the submit-all id at the submit button by accident.  Even with the id, it's just stuck at the page.

 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 419 (unknown status) <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: There are several problems, I've updated my answer to address all of them.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Don't Panic. I updated my current codes here as I'm still still facing the same issue.

Comment: @Enovyne your updated code works for me, though I am not testing your Controller code, only that the file is correctly posted and the server receives the expected data.  `"display argument supplied for foreach()"` is not an error msg I have ever seen, and it doesn't show up in Google.  Is it really what you see, and what is throwing it, PHP or JS?  Also, are you sure the right controller/method are being reached?  What does browser dev tools show (check network and console)?

Comment: the error message "argument supplied for foreach() doesn't show up anymore." That is for the PHP code. In the console,it displays Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 419 (unknown status) <!DOCTYPE html> which is pretty strange. It simply stays on the page.

Comment: @Enovyne OK, this is really a new question - `argument supplied for foreach()` was thrown bcs you were trying to access `files` instead of `file`, which did not exist (incidentally your question says `display argument supplied for foreach()` which is pretty misleading, as it not the error msg you saw). For your new problem, `419` is typically bcs your CSRF token check is failing.  I've updated my anwser, again.